# How can I specify in wix that the resulting MSI installs files depending on system architecture (x64 vs ARM64)?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, cpu-architecture

For our product we don't want to bother the user with different installers depending on system architecture. Now we want to install only the *x64* binaries on an *x64* Windows and only *ARM64* binaries on a native *ARM64* Windows.

It puzzles me that there seems to be no built-in functionality for this. Of course I could write a custom action and find out via `IsWow64Process2`, but this seems a bit overengineered for such a simple thing!

Did I overlook some easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [WiX Package element](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html), this could be specified using the `Platform` attribute, however the docs also state that this attribute should be avoided in favour of the `-arch` flag on the command line.

Comment: That would restrict the whole installer to one platform and thus require several installers (one for each platform). We explicitly don't want that. We want to pack binaries for all platforms into one single package and decide during install-time which of them are actually copied to the user system.